# Change color of an image using gm

Tags: node.js, image, colors, gm

I have a png image and I want to change the color of that image using the GraphicsMagick node module. 
Does GraphicsMagick provide the functionality to change the color of an image?.
Is there any other library through which I can change the color of an image.

Comment: I want to change the white color image into red color

Answer (score 0):

```
var gm = require('../')
  , dir = __dirname + '/imgs'

gm(dir + "/original.jpg")
  .crop(140,100)
  .background("#FF0000")
  .extent(340,300)
  .write(dir + '/background.jpg', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.dir(arguments)
    console.log(this.outname + " created  ::  " + arguments[3])
});
```

See here some examples: https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/tree/master/examples

Comment: This doesn't _change_ the color of the image. It crops the image and adds a red colored background.

Comment: Yes, @RobC is right it just cropped the image and added the red color background.